# bat file fails to execute commands

Tags: batch-file

I have the following bat file:

```
set dir=%1
create-react-native-app %dir%
cd %dir%
call npm install --save react-native-ignore-warnings
call npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev
call npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-2
```

after create-react-native-app the bat file stops execution

Comment: If `create-react-native-app` is itself implemented as a batch file, this is in fact what happens. You will, in that case, need to `CALL create-react-native-app %dir%` instead.

Comment: thanks, that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your response to my comment, `create-react-native-app` is implemented as a batch file. In Windows (and in fact dating back many years to DOS), if you invoke a batch file from within another batch file, Windows/DOS "forgets" the first batch file. To prevent this, you need to `CALL` the second batch file from the first.

(as given, you don't actually need the variable `dir`; you can just use `%1`:

```
CALL create-react-native-app %1
cd %1
call npm install --save react-native-ignore-warnings
call npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev
call npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-2
```

)